# Can I use UBUNTU SERVER AS A REGULAR COMPUTER?

Tags: system-installation

I am in the middle of installing Ubuntu server, but, I will not lie, I have no clue how to use it. 
Can I use it as a desktop or any help or how to start using? 
what are my expectations? 
Will I end up seeing a terminal only? 
Any advice? 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Server is not intended for home use, only for server use.

However, if you want to make it suitable for home usage, you may in the installation when it gets to the "Select Desktop" (or something like that) part, select the normal desktop, or KDE, LXDE, Cinnamon, etc.

If you choose no desktop at that part, then when the installation is done, you can install any desktop environment. Here's 3 codes to install Unity, KDE and LXDE (and only install one of these):

Unity:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

KDE:

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

LXDE:

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

If you want more than 2 desktops, you'll need to get GDM.

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

You should be good now.

Answer (score 0):

On load you will see a terminal line 
If you run apt-get install ubuntu-desktop 
you will end up with the functional equivalent of Desktop Edition. While also having all that the server package has

Comment: I am installing but, how would I be able to get the Desktop?

Comment: Your looking for a server edition with a gui. So when the install completes you will see a terminal window type in 'apt-get install ubuntu-desktop' w/o the quote and it will download your graphical user interface. It will essentially be a server edition with a gui with all the desktop features